# В чём разница между запуском скрипта из командной строки и по cron?

Tags: linux

Есть некий скрипт для бэкапа некоторых каталогов с документами на сервере. Внутри скрипта стоит вызов rsync. Утилита конектится с сервером по ssh. Возникла странная ситуация:

Если запускаю скрипт из командной строки, то он нормально логинится на сервер и выполняет бэкап.

Если же запускаю его по времени с помощью cron, то выдаётся :

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

И сервер закрывает соединение. Понятно, что какая-то проблема в окружении запускаемого процесса. Однако - в чём именно дело?! Переменные

```
LOGNAME=...
PASSWORD=...
```

крутил по всякому.

Comment: Разница в пользователе и переменных окружения. В этом можно убедиться вставив в скрипт строчку `env &> log.txt`

Comment: Представьте пример запуска скрипта в кроне и в терминале и от какого пользователя происходит запуск в консоле и от какого пользователя устанавливался crontab

Comment: **Разница в пользователе и переменных окружения.** Это я и сам понял.

**от какого пользователя устанавливался crontab** - в том-то и дело, что пользователь везде один и тот же! Я распечатывал (через эхо) значение LOGNAME - всегда одно!

Answer (score 4):

> Permission denied (publickey,password)

вероятно, аутентификация должна у вас производиться по паре секретный-публичный ключ.

для этого либо программе *rsync* должен быть явно указан секретный ключ, либо она воспользуется тем, что находится в каталоге `~/.ssh` того пользователя, от имени которого она запущена.

скорее всего, *cron-задание* у вас выполняется от имени пользователя *root* (а в эмуляторе терминала — от имени «рядового» пользователя). потому программа *rsync* и «не находит» подходящего секретного ключа.

---

варианты решения (в порядке «убывания разумности» с моей точки зрения):

- записать само задание в *crontab-файл* нужного пользователя, выполнив от имени этого пользователя (а не *root-а*) команду:

  ```
  $ crontab -e
  ```
- выполнять программу *rsync* от имени пользователя, воспользовавшись программой *sudo*:

  ```
  sudo -u пользователь rsync ...
  ```
- указать программе *rsync* (точнее, вызываемой ею программе *ssh*) файл с секретным ключом (например, `/home/пользователь/.ssh/id_rsa`), добавив опцию `-e команда`:

  ```
  rsync -e 'ssh -i /home/пользователь/.ssh/id_rsa' ...
  ```
- скопировать секретный ключ из каталога «рядового» пользователя в каталог пользователя *root* (создав при необходимости каталог и установив для него и его содержиого «правильные» права):

  ```
  $ sudo mkdir -p /root/.ssh
  $ sudo cp /home/пользователь/.ssh/id_rsa /root/.ssh
  $ sudo chown -R root:root /root/.ssh
  $ sudo chmod -R go= /root/.ssh
  ```

---

если же, как написано в комментариях, *cron* выполняет задачу от того же самого пользователя, что и при запуске в эмуляторе терминала, то следует сравнить вывод команды *env*, выполненной в эмуляторе терминала и программой *cron*. какие-то ключевые (для выполняемого скрипта) переменные присутствуют в одном месте и отсутствуют (или имеют иное значение) — в другом. сравнивать удобнее командой `diff -ruaN файл1 файл2`, предварительно отсортировав оба файла программой *sort*.

в первую очередь стоит обратить внимание на наличие и значение переменной `HOME`. ведь по умолчанию именно в каталоге `$HOME/.ssh` разыскивается секретный ключ.

Comment: **вероятно, аутентификация должна у вас производиться по паре секретный-публичный ключ.** - Совершенно верно! Т.е. если я захожу по ssh на сервер, то указываю только логин. Пароль там уже есть.

Comment: **$ crontab -e** Именно так я и делал.

Comment: **указать программе rsync (точнее, вызываемой ею программе ssh) файл с секретным ключом** - Ура !!!! Помогло !!!

Comment: **сравнивать удобнее командой diff** - ну, сравнивать тут было особо нечего! В env, которое в скрипте, запускаемом из консоли - 78 строк, а в том, которое по крону - 17... Но, что меня изумляет - LOGNAME совпадают! А вот переменная USER присутствует только при ручном запуске.

Comment: **более существенно наличие и значение переменной $HOME** - Наверное, Вы правы!